# Neural network function forecasting

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm trying to predict sinus function values using neural network toolbox provided with matlab.

I need the net to be able to predict function value for a single period based on two or more periods. I thought it is not very difficult, because sin is simple function.

Unfortunately it seems that my network predicts everything except what I expect it to.

Here is my code:

```
x = 0:0.01:20;
y = sin(x);


net = fitnet(7);

net = init(net);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

net = train(net, x, y);


x = 21:0.01:25;
y = sin(x);

z = sim(net, x);

plot(x, [y; z]);
```

And here is the plot:
[image]

I tried changing argument passed to `fitnet` and using `netff` with various parameters. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The first point is that normalization during study ( normalization of training set ). I can't see, that you applied it in some way. Another point of consideration is normalization of testing set, I can't find how you applied normalization to testing set. And yet one more consideration, your test set has no representation at all in training set. I mean you trained network in range [0;20] and checked results [21;25]. Normalization will help you to fix this issue. As few hints of normalization I propose you to consider converting values for study into radians, and scale values in radians from [-1;1]